# RSpec Integration Testing - Testing how many anchor tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have never dabbled outside of model testing when it comes to testing, and I am currently learning how to create my own user authentication instead of relying on Devise. It has been a little bit of time since I have worked with RSpec and not only would I like a little sanity check for syntax, but I can not figure out a way to confirm that my log in and sign up is indeed disappearing when a user logs in.

Here is my current users_logins_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "UsersLogins", type: :request do

  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
  end

  it "login with invalid information" do
    get login_path
    expect(response).to render_template(:new)
    post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
    expect(response).to render_template(:new)
    expect(flash).to be_present
    get root_path
    expect(flash).not_to be_present
  end

  it "login with valid information" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: "password"}
    expect(response).to redirect_to(@user)
    follow_redirect!
    expect(response).to render_template('users/show')
    # expect(page).to have_selector('a', login_path)

  end
end
```

Emphasizing the last test because that is the one that fails. I believe that if I were to put ID's on the tags that I want to check I would be able to circumvent the problem that I am having with methods that I understand. My intention is to learn how to manipulate my tests without having to find workarounds that change my code outside of the test, despite how little of a change that would be.

The other question is dealing with redirects. When I want to redirect to the @user url_path of @user, how does RSpec different when interpreting the call? I know that in Rails if I had something like

```
= link_to "Profile", current_user
```

it would automatically interpret it as

```
= link_to "Profile", user_path(current_user)
```

assuming my user resources within routes.rb.

If anyone can recommend some good tutorials for Rspec with Capybara for Integration and Feature testing that would be awesome, and any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to make this as a Integration test instead of a feature test (which to my understanding those are kept within the requests directory and are "less readable" because they aren't so much as user stories but still are checking functionality of the site)

### EDIT:

So I figured out part of my problem. I put in a debugger and was able to figure out that my user wasn't actually logging in correctly.

Here is the method that I am using to digest a password within the factory.

user.rb

```
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end
```

factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:id) { |n| n }
    sequence(:name) { |n| "foo#{n}" }
    email { "#{name}@example.com" }
    password_digest User.digest('password')
  end
end
```

The problem seems to be that my user login credentials are invalid and I am not exactly sure why.

### FINAL EDIT - SOLVED

Okay, so I got it working. My problem with the user being incorrect was an easy fix. Instead of using `password_digest` within the factory I just did changed it to `password` and `password_confirmation` and it began the redirect. I originally had FactoryGirl.create(user) and have been switching between the two throughout testing, but in order for this to work with the confirmation it had to be create.

The next issue was actually with assert_select.

Here is the error:

```
NotImplementedError:
   Implementing document_root_element makes assert_select work without needing to specify an element to select from.
```

I did end up finding a solution. Apparently this is with the latest version of RSpec and the solution that I had found was to set the document_root_element.

Within my spec/support I created a module

```
**spec/support/assert_select_root.rb    
module AssertSelectRoot
  def document_root_element
    html_document.root
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include AssertSelectRoot, :type => :request
end
```

I guess this was required for tests within spec/requests tests

Comment: A lot of my issues that I was having was because I was following Hartl's tutorial for custom authentication, but I wanted to use RSpec over minitest and a custom view for an already running application.

Answer (score 0):

Joe. You should keep in mind that FactoryGirl.build do not create database instance. So your Users table may be empty if you don't seed it before test.
I suggest you to use .create instead of .build.

Comment: I've gone back and forth between using create and build. When using build I even tried adding a "fake" id to simulate it during the test. I was following Hartl's tutorial and was trying to use the password_digest with BCrypt, but a simple change to FactoryGirl just solved part of my problem. I added a password and password_confirmation to the factory and it solved the problem of not having a correct user. I'm editing my post with the second problem.